# Is it equivalent in all senses to put arr[ ] and *arr as parameters in function prototypes?

Tags: c

Let's say I have some function `function`, are the following prototypes completely equivalent in all senses?

```
sometype function(sometype2 arr[],...);
sometype function(sometype2 * arr,...,);
```

I think they are, but my c professor never really explained that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the prototypes given are equivalent.

When you pass an array to a function, what's actually happening is that a pointer to the first element of the array is being passed to the function.  This is referred to as the array decaying to a pointer when passed as a parameter.

In both cases, the value of `sizeof arr` will return the size of a pointer type, typically 4 or 8 on most systems, instead of the size in bytes of the array.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of the compiler, they're both pointers.

For example, you can assign `NULL` to `arr` in the body of the function when `sometype2 arr[]` is a function parameter and modify the address itself; the following compiles just fine:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void
fun1(
    int *foo)
{
    /* foo = &foo[1] */
    ++foo;

    foo = NULL;
}

void
fun2(
    int foo[])
{
    /* foo = &foo[1] */
    ++foo;

    foo = NULL;
}

int
main(
    void)
{
    int x[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    fun1(x);
    fun2(x);
}
```

As a result, it's mostly just a semantic difference for humans. There may be different schools of thought on how you "should" code this, but it's really up to whatever style guide you need/want to follow. If it's a matter of personal choice, you can use the pointer version if you want to make the pointer decay explicit, or you may use the array version if you want to make it clear that the function accepts an array rather than a pointer to a single item.

However, in both functions, the function parameters are treated equally as pointers with `sizeof(foo)` being equivalent to `sizeof(int *)` inside the function.